# How to use Google style token authentication in Web APIs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, identity

I have an internal use web site that will be exposed over the Internet for ease of use on mobile devices.  The web site is MVC 5 and will communicate with a Web API on a different server.  The user will enter their Windows account information on the login page which will be authenticated against our Active Directory service.  Once authenticated I would like to create an authentication token for use for subsequent calls to the MVC site as well as calls to the various other Web APIs.

At first we were just going to use Basic authentication since all channels of communication are over SSL however we have one Web API that will not have access to our AD but will have access to a central database that may contain token information.

Any examples or documentation about how to secure enterprise Web APIs would be fantastic.  I can't find much information about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this would be to create a custom ActionFilterAttribute and override the `OnActionExecuting` method.

```
public class AuthenticateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
     {
          //grab token from httprequest in the actionContext
          //and authenticate it against the token in the database

         if(/*token is NOT authenticated*/)
         {
              //set unauthorised response
              var response = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
             //and set the httpresponse in the actionContext to the unauthorised response
             actionContext.Response = response;
             //then return
             return;
         }
     }
}
```

You can then apply this attribute to any actions or methods in your api you wish to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using thinktecture's IdentityServer.
https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3

v3 Beta 1 was just released.  Looks promising.
Support for OpenID Connect and OAuth2.0.

They have several client samples that you can download from a different repository.
https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients